# Send emails in Marketing Cloud without an email address in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, transactional-messaging-api

Im creating a transactional journey that is passing along an ID, which is related to a contact (field on Contact object in Salesforce) and which im pulling into Marketing Cloud. Im currently using ampscript to retrieve first name, last name, etc from the contact table using this ID, however when testing the journey, its giving me the "required email address not found" error, as the API connected to the journey is not passing along an email address. Is it possible to lookup the email address from the ID the API is sending? I think I could create an automation to populate a new data extension, but this defeats the purpose of a transactional fed journey, as I dont want to wait every hour for the emails to send.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not passing the non-mandatory argument email in the API call, the journey will retrieve the email associated with the contact key (subscriber key = contact key), mandatory argument, in All Subscribers. If not found, no send. I'm not aware of another way to specify the recipient.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using Transactional API, sending Email requires either an Email to be passed in the API call, or an Email linked to the provided Contact Key (via Subscriber Key).

There is unfortunately no other way to specify the recipient address.

Comment: @JohnDillinger, my comment as been posted as an answer, please consider accepting it ;)